# Read csv and join lines on a ASCII character pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a csv file in following format -

```
id1,"When I think about the short time that we live and relate it to á
the periods of my life when I think that I did not use this á
short time."
id2,"[ On days when I feel close to my partner and other friends.  á
When I feel at peace with myself and also experience a close á
contact with people whom I regard greatly.]"
```

I want to read in pyspark. My code is -

```
schema = StructType([
    StructField("Id", StringType()),
    StructField("Sentence", StringType()),
  ])

df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv") \
        .option("header", "false") \
        .option("inferSchema", "false") \
        .option("delimiter", "\"") \
        .schema(schema) \
        .load("mycsv.csv")
```

But the result I am getting is -

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Id                                                           | Sentence                                                           |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id1,                                                          |When I think about the short time that we live and relate it to á  |
|the periods of my life when I think that I did not use this á |null                                                               |
|short time.                                                   |"                                                                  |
```

...

I want to read it in 2 column one containing `Id` and other `Sentence`.
And the sentences should join on ASCII character `á` as I see it is reading on next line without getting the delimiter .

My output should look like this -

```
    +--------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    | Id                                                           | Sentence                                                                 |
    +--------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    |id1,                                                          |When I think about the short time that we live and relate it to the periods of my life when I think that I did not use this short time. |
```

I have considered only one id in example.
What modification is needed in my code?

Comment: Read the csv as text file. Split the rdd by this separator ',\"' so that you will have id1 as rdd[0] element and the text as rdd[1] element. Put those in the dataframe.

Comment: `data =sc.textFile("mycsv.csv")
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data
        .map(lambda line: line.split(",\""))
        .filter(lambda line: len(line)>1)
        .map(lambda line: (line[0],line[1]))).toDF("Id", "Sentence")`
I tried like this also but it is reading only one line and skipping all other lines of id1.

Comment: I understood the problem, but not quite sure how to solve it. Let you know if I can come up with something. I think before splitting the rdd we should try to join lines on the ASCII character to put it in one line. Only then we can use the above code.

Comment: Yes we need to join lines on getting `á` and then split into 2 rdd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just update Spark to 2.2 or later, if you haven't done this already and use `multiline` option:

```py
df = spark.read
    .option("header", "false") \
    .option("inferSchema", "false") \
    .option("delimiter", "\"") \
    .schema(schema) \
    .csv("mycsv.csv", multiLine=True)
```

If you do that, you can remove `á` with `regexp_replace`:

```
df.withColumn("Sentence", regexp_replace("Sentence", "á", "")
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. I was not aware of multiLine feature. And I have to add `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at top of file to read the non ASCII character `á`.